# How can I add a new row at the top of my datatable in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, row

Every time I add a new row in my datatable (via commandbutton "new Feedback") it is added at the bottom of the datatable. How can I add it and make sure that it will appear at the top?

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.content}" ></h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="send message"
        action="#{helloBean.multiAufruf}">
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton value="new Feedback"
        action="#{helloBean.gettingFeedbackMulti}">
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:dataTable value="#{helloBean.sentMessagesList}" var="message">
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{message.content}"></h:inputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{message.time}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{message.idList}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{message.feedbackz}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action method for the command `gettingFeedbackMulti`, you are probably doing something like this

```
sentMessagesList.add(message);
```

Just change it to use `add()` with index argument like this

```
sentMessagesList.add(0, message);
```

This will add it to index 0 of your list